# Is the empty set in this quotient set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Let $S$ be a non-empty set and $\mathcal{A}$ a class of subsets of $S$ and define the following equivalence relation $\sim_{\mathcal{A}}$ on $S$;

$$s\sim_{\mathcal{A}}t\Longleftrightarrow 1_{A}(s)=1_{A}(t)\hspace{20pt}\forall A\in\mathcal{A}$$

Define $\mathcal{A}_{\tau}=\{[s]_{\sim{\mathcal{A}}}:s\in S\}$ to be the set of equivalence classes (the quotient set).

**Question: Is it true that $\emptyset\in\mathcal{A}_{\tau}$??**

Suppose $\emptyset\in\mathcal{A}_{\tau}$ and choose any $s,t\in\emptyset$. By definition of $\sim_{\mathcal{A}}$ this means $1_{A}(s)=1_{A}(t)$ for all $A\in\mathcal{A}$ vacuously, since of course $s,t$ do not exist. Thus no contradiction arises but this is not a proof that $\emptyset\not\in\mathcal{A}_{\tau}$ is true.

This seems related to the following question [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2193873/is-wikipedia-wrong-when-stating-that-emptyset-has-exactly-one-partition-name), but I wanted to make sure I was not being too lazy with applying this "vacuous" argument.

Comment: $\emptyset$ is **never** an equivalence class, no matter the equivalence relation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Showing that it would not be inconsistent if the empty set were in $\mathcal A_\tau$ does not prove that it is in $\mathcal A_\tau$, as you hint towards.

Look at the definition of $\mathcal A_\tau$. Is $\emptyset =[s]$ for some $s \in S$? Since we always have, at a minimum, $s\in [s]$, the answer is "No".

Notice that this doesn't depend on your particular equivalence. It's true for any equivalence relation. Even if  $\emptyset$ was in your original set, its equivalence class, $[\emptyset]$, would, at a minimum, contain $\emptyset$, and even the set containing just the empty set is not the empty set.

Comment: One additional way of seeing that the argument given in the OP is insufficient is that it "works" for any subset of any equivalence class $[s]$.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanZ and +1 certainly for (I am sure) being correct that $\emptyset\not\in\mathcal{A}_{\tau}$, but  I didn't help my cause with my example that does not prove $\emptyset\not\in\mathcal{A}$. If I were to re-phrase I would ask why such a argument appealing to "the vacuous statement" as given in the link would not work in this case leading to the trivial conclusion $\emptyset\in\mathcal{A}_{\tau}$? For instance what about the following: for all $s,t\in \emptyset$ then $s\sim_{\mathcal{A}}t$, this being vacuously true since $s,t$ do not exist?

Comment: I see however this is in-adequate in the sense that, if indeed correct, would only "prove" $\emptyset$ is contained in some equivalence class, and all sets contain the empty set (?) so this is not saying anything wrong.

Comment: @GregMartin thanks for your comment, I think I see that you mean my example applied to a subset of some $[s]_{\mathcal{A}}\in\mathcal{A}_{\tau}$ simply leads us to conclude $\emptyset\subset[s]_{\mathcal{A}}$ which is true of any set (?) and thus the example proves nothing